# Powershell SMO objects

Tags: database, windows, sql-server-2008, powershell, backup

I am trying to learn powershell, recently i was struck in the query that how can find out the objects in the assembly's
example:

I have loaded the Powershell sql assembly

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.sqlserver.smo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.sqlserver.smoextended") | Out-Null
```

For denoting the server, I need to add `New-Object ("Microsoft.sqlserver.Management.SMO.Server")`

For backup database `New-Object ("microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup")`

My question is how can I get all the objects list and to use in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PoSh is just a wrapper here. For learning what SMO classes and methods are available, you need to look at the SMO documentation. Start with [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

For a list of all classes in SMO, again I reffer you to the product documentation, please look at [SQL Server Management Objects Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh247097.aspx) (the list on the left hand side has all the SMO namespaces, click on each namespace to see all classes available in each namespace).